# Debug localhost on app engine with Intellij Idea and gradle

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am using IntelliJ community addition and building an app engine standard environment application with Gradle. I was using Android Studio before migrating to IntelliJ and endpoint framework. I am not able to debug my localhost. I added jvmFlags as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle

```
appengine {
      run {
        jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005']
      }
    }
```

And deployed my app to local with debug button. But the app didn't deploy and stuck in
**Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8080**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you are doing to debug and what results you are getting?

Comment: @saiyr Thanks for replying. I am debugging my localhost cloud endpoint.

Comment: @saiyr Did you check?

Comment: Your config and log seem inconsistent. Did you change the port to 8080 in build.gradle? At any rate, the log message indicates that the app is waiting for the debugger to attach to continue. So you need to configure a debugger in IntelliJ to attach to the port listed in the log (which in your pasted log is 8080, not 5005).

Comment: Hi @saiyr. Sorry for a late reply. Actually, I solved the problem. I had to do is run the app first. Then I had to attach the debugger with remote config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I was making a stupid mistake. Even if anyone who is facing a similar problem please follow [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/1888).