# Access App Engine localhost using IP address in Cloud Endpoint Framework

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Previously, I was using this to access App Engine on the IPv4 address in the build.gradle file:

```
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    httpPort = 8888
...
}
```

But after upgrading to Cloud Endpoint plugin, this option has removed. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the new `app-gradle-plugin`, you want this:

```
appengine {
  run {
    host = "0.0.0.0"
    port = 8080
  }
}
```

See [new plugin documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference).

Comment: It worked :D. Can you answer me this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404237/debug-app-engine-on-intellij-idea-with-endpoint-framework-and-gradle